# In Java, How can I programmatically identify a hidden file in a zip?

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I would like to ignore hidden files when extracting a zip. 
Is there any way i can identify that a ZipEntry belongs to a 'hidden' file?

Comment: What is a hidden file? On Linux it's a file which starts with a dot, on Windows it's probably a file attribute.

Comment: On Windows it's definitely a file attribute. Which is nothing more than a flag in a record on the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on Windows, there is no way to do it. The ZipEntry doesn't contain such information. You might be able to write your own zipper to store the information in ExtraInfo field.

On Unix, you can workaround by checking the leading dot in the filename.

Comment: *The ZipEntry doesn't contain such information*. True, but the actual zip entry in the zip file *does* include this information. ZIP allows file attributes to be stored with the Zip Entry. A zip created from an NTFS volume can store the file attributes, including the Hidden attribute if it is present on the original file. Not all zip libraries handle these attributes, and in particular the zip classes that are builtin to Java may ignore that metadata (I don't know; will take your word for it), but it isn't strictly speaking "impossible".

Comment: You get access to the file attributes using DotNetZip, for example. The reference document for this is here: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/640bac96-0fb1-51fe-36d0-8a923c0d467f.htm I understand that is .NET, not Java, but the point is: technically, it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isHidden%28%29

It should have been preserved when they created the zip.

Comment: Uh I imagine because your providing "answers" which are senseless.  The hidden attribute is a flag on ntfs (or a dot-prefix on unix,) what makes you think a file has any idea whether or not it's hidden, especially when passing between filesystems? Educate yourself, before attempting to educate others: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/08/25/ntfs-file-attributes.aspx

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Well, that's exactly what that method does. Remember, the File object isn't a handle to the file directly. It's just a bunch of metadata about the file. The exact text at the link I provided is "Tests whether the file named by this abstract pathname is a hidden file. The exact definition of hidden is system-dependent. On UNIX systems, a file is considered to be hidden if its name begins with a period character ('.'). On Microsoft Windows systems, a file is considered to be hidden if it has been marked as such in the filesystem."

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Also, even if I was wrong, there's no need to be snarky about it. Sometimes people are wrong. You downvote wrong answers, to be sure, but it's also preferred to explain why they are wrong so the answer can be edited or deleted appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Java class `ZipEntry` does not maintain file flags by design, as the accepted answer found.

If your usecase has not reserved the comment tag, you could fill it with file flag info, as e.g.
windows command line `attrib <file>` delivers.
In order to mark only hidden files, that would be

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("foo").setComment("H");
```

**EDIT**

There is also an `extra` tag, designed to take additional implementation specific information as generic container, see
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439166/9437799)